C++ how to do structured binding into existing variables?
I have some code that looks like this (EDIT: my condition depends on the first computation):
int res2;
int res1 = fancy_computation(blah, &res2);

if (condition(res1))
    res1 = fancy_computation_but_slightly_different(blah2, &res2);

do stuff with res1 and res2;

Naturally, using pointers to fake a pair of retvals is no bueno, and I'd love to replace it with structured bindings:
auto [res1, res2] = fancy_computation(blah);

if (condition(res1))
    auto [res1, res2] = fancy_computation_but_slightly_different(blah2);

do stuff with res1 and res2;

Naturally this gives me warnings about the second binding shadowing the first variables, which honestly I don't care about, but the project rules say warnings are errors. Also, the maintainers have previously rejected using the std::tie hack. Declaring new variables res1b res2b wouldn't work either, because for the purposes of the following block I'd have to re-assign res1 = res1b res2 = res2b, which would very much defeat the purpose of "making it more readable than pointer-retvals".
Is there any hope to fix this, and be rid of the res2 pointer?
I've reviewed some other SO questions, none directly answer this question (altho many say "no luck doing that usecase with structured bindings", which I kind of expect here...)

Yep, no luck.  structured bindings introduce new names.  You'd need to use the std::tie trick.

Well, the warning is on point here, because after the if the inner structured binding disappears and the outer one remains unaffected, so that code would behave wrongly.

Also, why would the std::tie option be rejected?

std::tie is not a hack. It exists specifically for this use case.

My first version with tie was fairly ugly, as tie itself is ugly, but this latest attempt is less ugly, sufficiently so that maybe tie would be accepted this time.

@YurkoFlisk I'm not sure about the scope, because I just wrote a version with tie. I changed what had been a struct to a tuple to make tie work, and now I don't get any warnings about shadowing locals, and yet the resulting functionality is identical to the posted version. So I think as-posted still behaves correctly

How do you know the functionality is identical? Did you test the posted version in the case where if branch is taken and you use res1 or res2 outside the if?

Because we don't have language tuples, we need to use std::tie. Someday, we can write [res1, res2] = fancy_computation ();. The situation is not completely bad because the current limitations encourage a more functional programming style. Actually, your code is precisely non-functional; IMO, the interface of the functions you are using is not optimal in the first place, at least for your use case. The function is computing stuff that is going to be partially used for some users, this means that there exists is a more fundamental function that should be part of the interface.

alfC in the real codebase, there's two NNs, one much larger and smaller. in most cases we use the larger, for its better accuracy, but in certain edge cases the speed of the smaller one is better. but in rare cases we actually take the small net result and decide that we, in fact, do want the big net result anyways, and that's the condition. not sure there's any more fundamental function there, other than "infer the bignet" and "infer the smallnet".

@YurkoFlisk the project has a functionality test, and i tested using the shadowing-auto and just using tie the second time -- using tie the second time was functionally identical to shadowing-auto the second time.

And I did wind up using tie inside the conditional, and this was accepted by maintainers. Overall this second attempt was cleaner, cleaner enough to make the tie overall more readable than my first try a year ago. My thanks to all answers and commenters.

Then the functionality test is likely incomplete and doesn't test the case of if condition being true, because shadowing auto definitely mustn't work (or, at least, the second function just returns the same thing as the first for the tested inputs, thus masking the fact that shadowing occured).

You can use lambda:
auto [res1, res2] = [&] {
  auto [res1, res2] = fancy_computation(blah);

  if (condition(res1))
    return fancy_computation_but_slightly_different(blah2);
  
  return std::pair{res1, res2};
}();

// do stuff with res1 and res2


nice use of an immediately invoked lambda expression. +1

ah, unfortunately i neglected to put in my code reduction that the condition depends on the first fancy result, if (condition(res1))

still tho, that's a neat little trick if i could reorder the condition

yes it occurred to me in bed that, conditional order or not, the key idea of using scope to un-collide two layers of the same names can be used either way.
